# Run-time error '3708': Parameter Object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided

Tags: sql-server, vba

I trying to run a stored procedure from an Access form using VBA code but I keep getting the error ("**Run-time error '3708': Parameter Object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided**"). Could someone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

.
1. I have a table called "**CurrTbl**" and a stored procedure called "**ManageCurrency**"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CurrTbl](
[CurrencyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CurrencyCountry] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[CurrencyName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[ISOCODE] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
[lg_user] [varchar](150) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_CurrencyName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CurrencyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CurrTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_CurrTbl_lg_user]  DEFAULT (original_login()) FOR [lg_user]
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[ManageCurrency]
    @CurCountry varchar(250),
    @CurName varchar(250),
    @ICode varchar(3),
    @Flag smallint = 0 OUTPUT,
    @SP_Message Varchar(MAX) = '' OUTPUT

AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @si AS BIGINT = 0;
    If (ISNULL(@CurCountry,'') <> '' and ISNULL(@ICode,'') <> '')
        BEGIN
            merge dbo.CurrTbl as T
            USING (Select @CurCountry AS CurrencyCountry, @CurName AS CurrencyName, @ICode as ISOCode) AS S
            ON (T.CurrencyCountry = S.CurrencyCountry and T.ISOCode = S.ISOCode)
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
            THEN INSERT (CurrencyCountry,CurrencyName,ISOCode)
                 VALUES (@CurCountry,@CurName,@ICode)
            WHEN MATCHED
            THEN UPDATE SET T.CurrencyName = @CurName;
            -- Getting the lastest scope identity of the last entry
            SELECT @si = CurrencyID from dbo.CurrTbl where CurrencyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END
If (ISNULL(@si,'')<> '') SET @SP_Message = 'Operation Sucessful'; Set @Flag = 1;
If (ISNULL(@si,'')= '') Set @SP_Message = 'Operation Not Sucessful'; Set @Flag = 0;
END
```

2. I have a VBA Code that runs the procedure

   ```
   Public Type SP_Variable

       Name As String
       Value As String

   End Type

   Private Sub Command0_Click()

       Dim SQL_Var(3) As SP_Variable
       Dim Out_Var(2) As SP_Variable
       SQL_Var(1).Name = "@CurCountry"
       SQL_Var(1).Value = "KAMPALA"
       SQL_Var(2).Name = "@CurName"
       SQL_Var(2).Value = "KAMPALA SHILLING"
       SQL_Var(3).Name = "@ICode"
       SQL_Var(3).Value = "KSH"
       Out_Var(1).Name = "@Flag"
       Out_Var(1).Value = ""
       Out_Var(2).Name = "@SP_Message"
       Out_Var(2).Value = ""

       Call InsertProcedure("ManageCurrency", SQL_Var, 3, Out_Var, 2)

   End Sub



   Public Function InsertProcedure(ProcedureName As String, ByRef Input_Variables() As SP_Variable, InputVar As Integer, ByRef Output_Variables() As SP_Variable, OutputVar As Integer) As String 

       Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
       Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
       Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
       Dim sConnect As String
       sConnect = "driver={sql server};server=Svr;Database=Data_DB;UID=user;PWD=password;"

       '' Establish connection.
       Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
       Conn.ConnectionString = sConnect
        Conn.Open
       '' Open recordset.
       Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
       cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
       cmd.CommandText = ProcedureName
       cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
       cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
       cmd.Parameters.Refresh

       ''For i = 1 To InputVar
       ''cmd.Parameters(SP_Variables(i).Name).Value = SP_Variables(i).Value
       ''cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Input_Variables(i).Name,  adVarChar, adParamInput, 350)
       ''cmd.Parameters.Item(Input_Variables(i).Name).Value = "'" & Input_Variables(i).Value & "'"
       cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CurCountry", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250, Input_Variables(3).Value)
       cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CurName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250, Input_Variables(3).Value)
       cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ICode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 3, Input_Variables(3).Value)

       ''Next i
       ''For i = 1 To OutputVar
       ''   ''cmd.Parameters(SP_Variables(i).Name).Value = SP_Variables(i).Value
       ''   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Output_Variables(i).Name, adVarChar, adParamInputOutput, 2000, Output_Variables(i).Value)
       ''  Next i

       Set rs = cmd.Execute
       SP_Message = cmd.Parameters("@SP_Message").Value
       SP_Flag = cmd.Parameters("@Flag").Value
       ' Process results from recordset, then close it.
       rs.Close
       Set rs = Nothing

   End Function
   ```

   That is the code.. Where am I going wrong

Comment: please try set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn instead of without the set   and you do not Need to specify cmd.Parameters.Refresh

Comment: Which line in your VBA code gives the error?  If you're going to use Parameters.Refresh, you should not be appending parameters.  Instead, use: Parameters.Item(_@Name_).Value = _Value_.  (In the commented line where you presumably tried this already, you set the value with encapsulating quotes which is unnecessary.)  I think your problem lies with your Output parameters.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly set those up in VBA, either.

Answer (score 1):

First off, since you are using `Parameters.Refresh`, you don't want to append your parameters to the parameter collection.  Instead, you should be using the following format when applying values to your **input** parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Item(Input_Variables(i).Name).Value = Input_Variables(i).Value
```

You had a line like this commented out in your VBA code.  I assume this means you tried it previously.  However, you encapsulated your `Input_Variables(i).Value` with single quotes (`'`).  You shouldn't do this.  You just need to make sure the value you are passing is of the same type that the parameter is set to.  (**NOTE:** *In your case, all of your `Input_Variables` are strings, so your `InsertProcedure` function will only work with stored procedures that have only string type parameters.*)

The same applies to your **output** parameters.  However, you probably don't need or want to set their value unless you are actually using them as both an Input and Output parameter.

One of your output parameters is of type `VARCHAR(MAX)`.  The `Parameters.Refresh` call is more than likely setting the `Size` of that parameter to 2,147,483,647 which is the maximum positive value of a `Long` type in VBA.  Unfortunately, and for reasons I admit I don't fully understand, the actual maximum size you can set an `adVarChar` parameter to is 1 less than that (2,147,483,646).  My best guess without looking in to it too much is that some kind of overhead is involved.  Leaving the size at 2,147,483,647 will result in the error you are receiving.

---

You have three options for solving the `VARCHAR(MAX)` ADO output parameter issue in VBA.  *(For all options below, I use the value 2147483646, but it can be any value greater than 0 and less than 2147483647.)*:

1. When using `Parameters.Refresh` to automatically set up the parameter collection of your command, you can manually override the setup of any `VARCHAR(MAX)` output parameter sizes to be something smaller than 2147483647:

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.Item(Output_Variables(i).Name).Size = 2147483646
   ```
2. Or, set up your stored procedure's `VARCHAR` out parameters with a size smaller than 2147483647:

   ```
   @SP_Message VARCHAR(2147483646) = '' OUTPUT
   ```
3. Or, don't use `Parameters.Refresh` and instead create all of your parameters manually and append them to the command's collection.  Your output parameter would be appended something like this:

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Output_Variables(i).Name, _
       adVarChar, _
       adParamInputOutput, _
       2147483646)
   ```

Comment: Very useful answer.